# Chemfig Adjacent Atom Help

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I am struggling with placing an H right beside my O. I don't want any dash between the O and H; just them beside each other.

Here is a photo of what I want:

[image]

Here is a photo of what I attempted:

[image]

Here is the code for what I attempted:

`\chemfig{\charge{-90=\: , -90:5pt=\scriptsize $ + $}{O}(H)(-[-4]3R)([2]-P(-[0]Br)(-[-4]Br))}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found out you don't need the parenthesis around the oxygen.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{\charge{-90=\: , -90:5pt=\scriptsize $ + $}{O}H(-[-4]3R)([2]-P(-[0]Br)(-[-4]Br))}
\end{document}
```

[image: Corrected molecule]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible ways to do this.
Joshua González showed the easiest and simplest to do.

But there are other ways you can choose if you need to.

You can use the command `\charge` or use an "invisible binding"

OBS: [-4] don't make sense, use [4], and use the binding before the spatial direction ([2]- is wrong, use -[2])

```
\chemfig{\charge{270=\:,270:5pt=\scriptsize$+$,0:2pt=H}{O}(-[4]3R)(-[2]P(-[0]Br)(-[4]Br))}
    
    \chemfig{\charge{270=\:,270:5pt=\scriptsize$+$}{O}(-[0,.25,,,,draw=none]H)(-[4]3R)(-[2]P(-[0]Br)(-[4]Br))}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution! Thank you!